# What is an array, what is the difference between array and objects and when and why use an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Hello I have a few questions:
Why is an array?
Why is the difference between array and object?
Why and when I need to use an array? 
Thanks for helping :);)

Comment: Object use string keys and are unordered.  Arrays use numeric keys and are maintain an order.

Comment: While we're happy to help fix code, we're not here to be your tutors.

Comment: An object is a collection of data with no real ordering. If you ask me for my height, weight and age, it doesn't really matter what order I tell you. Arrays are for lists of things. Tuesday always comes after Monday and Friday always comes before Saturday so the order matters.

Comment: In javascript there really isn't much of a difference.  You can define something as an array but then use object notation on it.  Likewise, you can define an object and then use key-value array style notation on it.  Javascript is very loose in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is a series of values with no defining keys:

`['one', 'two', 'three']`

An object uses keys which have values which can be anything within the scope of the language. eg: boolean, integer, string, object, array or event functions:

```
{
  one: {
    two: 'three'
  },
  four: ['five', 'six'],
  seven: 'eight',
  nine: 10,
  eleven: function () {},
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best definition for arrays and objects..